# Сообщение об ошибке не отображается во вкладке Elements в Dev Tools

Tags: django, google-chrome-devtools

Каким образом получить текст сообщения в форме регистрации на сайте, реализованном на Django? Элемент с сообщением об ошибке не отображается во вкладке Elements в Dev Tools.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

На стороннем ресурсе меня натолкнули на мысль, благодаря которой я нашел необходимую информацию. Подробно о решении текущего вопроса: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/form-validation-in-cypress/#validationmessage